# Display namespaces in order upon transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

Been trying to transform an XML using XSLT but the namespaces keep on rearranging after transfomration.

XML INPUT SAMPLE

```
<Document xmlns="uri" xmlns:xsi="url" xsi:schemaLocation="uri file">
```

After transformation it became like this

```
<Document xsi:schemaLocation="uri file" xmlns="uri" xmlns:xsi="url">
```

Any idea how I can have the same output using XSLT?

Here are some of my transformation, not saure if any of these affects  namespaces

```
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text() | processing-instruction() | comment()">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: how does it matter? A simple transformation with copy-of though works fine. can you post your xsl?

Comment: I dont have any transformation on that area, it just rearrange them in that order but I have some transformation, I posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of attributes is irrelevant in XML.  Your output is identical to your input from an XML Information Set perspective.

Ref: Item 10 in http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-infoset-20040204/#omitted

> Appendix D: What is not in the Information Set
>
> `10.` The order of attributes within a start-tag.

Accordingly, XSLT provides no control to the stylesheet writer to specify the order of attributes during serialization.

Note, also, the second bullet in the XML output method of serialization

http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt-xquery-serialization-20070123/#xml-output

> "The order of attribute and namespace nodes in the two trees MAY be
>   different."

Comment: So you mean that the attributes or namespaces in a document node will still be valid in any order they are displayed? because some of our customers preferred it that way and they are looking for the order as in 1, 2, 3 that is why I am looking for some solution. If there is none then its ok, i will just inform them its not possible, thanks

Comment: Yes, an element with attributes will be considered valid against a schema or DTD regardless of the order of the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Saxon 9.5 introduces a serialization option to allow you to control the order of attributes in the serialized XML. Although this is irrelevant from the point of view of a consuming application, it can help to make the XML more readable by humans. However, the control doesn't extend to namespaces. IIRC Saxon always serializes namespace declarations before (other) attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This template executes the below template for all attributes.

```
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

the order of execution could be the problem here....

Try using `<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />` instead of apply-templates.

Comment: Still the same output